# an emit works fine on chrome but doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

can someone explain why is that ,

the console log on the client side before the emit shows which mean the emit should be executed but nothing happens on the server .

server side :

```
  socket.on('newGame', () => {
    let roomID = playersController.getPlayerRoomID(socket.id)
    socket.broadcast.to(roomID).emit('newGame?', 'do u want to start a new game?')
    socket.on('confirmNewGame', () => {
        console.log('confirmed')
        io.to(roomID).emit('initialNewGame')
    })
})
```

client side :

```
socket.on('newGame?', (data) => {
    if (confirm(data)) {
        console.log('confirmed')
        // tested on chrome , doesn't emit on firefox don't know why 
        socket.emit('confirmNewGame')
    }
})
socket.on('initialNewGame', () => {
    initialNewGame()
})
```

Comment: For starters, you don't put `socket.on('confirmGame', ...)` inside of the `socket.on('newGame', ...)` callback.  That will never work properly as you will just accumulate duplicate handlers for `socket.on('newGame', ...)` each time `newGame` happens.

Comment: oops , thanks man .